# Using global variable in a dll for later use in Labview

Tags: c++, labview

i've written a dll in c++ in order to use it in Labview. The dll is compiled,  and i can import it in Labview. But when i try to use a function in it, it tells me this:"Error 1097 occurred at Call Library Function Node in dummyfunction(). LabVIEW:  An exception occurred within the external code called by a Call Library Function Node. The exception might have corrupted the LabVIEW memory. Save any work to a new location and restart LabVIEW."

I suspect because i use a global variable in the dll. Is that true? And how do i avoid that?

Comment: More details are needed. Can you show the code of dummyfunction() and how you call it from Labview?

Comment: Have you made sure that the calling convention LabVIEW is expecting matches how the DLL was compiled? Using a global variable should not be an issue as long as the DLL remains loaded. Please share the code you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My dll contains 4 functions, and all 4 functions have to access one variable. I cannot pass it as a Parameter, because it is not int or Long or string, and Labview only accepts that(the type is declared in another Header file). I'm not sure how a global is stored when Labview runs it

Answer (score 1):

If you build a debug version of the dll and use that version in your Labview code you can set breakpoints and step through the dll code.  I would set a breakpoint at the first function you call and step through the dll code until you find where the exception is occurring and then fix that problem.

I have only used Microsoft Visual Studio for doing that, and you have to specify Labview.exe as the executable.